# WPF: K.O. Can't Synchronize StoryBoards animations + Can't change application theme 

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

So I have a StackPanel menu which has a lot of buttons, each button must have a grid and inside 2 labels, the first for the icon, and the second for a small rectangle which indicates if this button is active or no. In addition, each button is linked to a page, and when the user clicks, the program displays the appropriate page.

When the program wants to get the user's attention to a specific page (for example, a notification page), an animation is started, in which we will flash the icon label (linked to that specific page) 2 times in red color for a short time, and it will be repeated every 10 seconds until the user clicks this button to see the notification.

**Problem N: 1**

It may happen that multiple notifications arrive at the same time from different pages, in this scenario we need to sync the `StoryBoards` so that the buttons will flash together every 10 seconds, otherwise you will see an unhappy result as each button will flash separately on others. My first thought was to bind something to the `BeginTime` of the `StoryBoard`, and make the `StoryBoard` wait for the running animations before starting. So, I jumped to the code, and as soon as I write this binding, an awesome exception pops up: **Could not freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use in feeds**, I google it and I have found that I am not allowed to use any binding or dynamic resource inside the `StoryBoard` `ControlTemplate`, so, I implement a small `DependencyProperty` in order to synchronize the animation, and this is the reason for which you'll notice this little line here:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Synchronizer}" Value="1"/>
```

C# Code

```
public partial class Layout : Window {
    public double Synchronizer { get; set; } = 0;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Synchronizer", typeof(double), typeof(Layout), new PropertyMetadata());
    public Layout(){
        {
            InitializeComponent(); DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

This Synchronizer is triggered due to this XAML Code:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:10">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="DataContext.Synchronizer" Duration="0:0:0.6">
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:0.0"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.6"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

> **Question N: 1** In yes / no answer, is there is any work around for this exception?

> **Question N: 2** Is there a better solution?

**Problem N: 2**

The application has several styles, mainly Dark.Xaml and Light.Xaml, as we already saw in the first issue, animation is used to indicate to the user that a specific page needs some attention. in dark mode we are going to flash the icon with a red color, and in light mode we are going to flash with a blue color, so let me focus on this part of the code:

```
<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
    <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#8B0000" KeyTime="0:0:0.2"/>
    <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#272725" KeyTime="0:0:0.3"/>
    <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#8B0000" KeyTime="0:0:0.4"/>
    <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#272725" KeyTime="0:0:0.6"/>
</ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

In general, I change the theme of the app using this C # code:

```
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Global.Themes[i]);
```

It works fine with elements that have a `DynamicResource` binding, but for `StaticResource` No !!

> **Question:** How can I change the app theme for this `StoryBoard` `ControlTemplate`, especially when there is no chance to use the `Binding` or the `Dynamic Resource`.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Menu.Button" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="35"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}, Path=Tag, Converter={StaticResource Check}, ConverterParameter=1|1}" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Synchronizer}" Value="1"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="Storyboard">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#8B0000" KeyTime="0:0:0.2"/>
                                            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#272725" KeyTime="0:0:0.3"/>
                                            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#8B0000" KeyTime="0:0:0.4"/>
                                            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#272725" KeyTime="0:0:0.6"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
        <Label>
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}, Path=Tag, Converter={StaticResource Check}, ConverterParameter=0|0}" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<StackPanel Name="Menu" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="35" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource Menu.Button}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The way to do the flashing is have one animation and one brush. Use that one brush on all the appropriate buttons. That could be from resources or tag of the parent window. Maybe applied using a datatrigger. In which case you could use a converter to generate the brush if that's convenient. A converter can easily be a singleton and that could go find colours to use for it's brush from applicaton.current.resources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot get around the problems you're facing using `XAML` alone. This is because `Storyboard`s in `XAML` are frozen and you cannot alter them in any way.

The way I handle this is that I move any animations that need dynamic capabilities such as databinding or theme switching into code and I make them available as XAML/attached behaviors.

Comment: I have never heard of this attached behavior technique, can you give me a little demo please? and based on your experience, can this solve my second problem, can I easily change the theme colors with this?